# Android relativeLaout Z-ordering bug

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-xml, z-order

I am facing a strange issue with z ordering in RelativeLayout.

**The Requirement**

View v2 should always be above btn1 irrespective whether its a TextView or a Button

**The Problem**

When i have two views a Button and TextView inside a RelativeLayout

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/dr1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="9dp" >
        </Button>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/v2"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="0"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" 
            android:clickable="false"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

but when view is rendered the TextView goes behind the button and when i replace TextView with Button the view becomes proper below code shows view v2 above btn1

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/dr1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="9dp" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/v2"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_red"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="0"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" 
            android:clickable="false"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

So when i have TextView above Button it will render it behind the Button but when i just Replace TextView tag with Button the view become proper and the view V2 is shown in front

---

A similar issue when i load a image in a ImageView, when a ImageView src is not set and a background is used the view behind the ImageView is visible and when a image src is set the view is earlier in front goes back

Comment: it look ok . please send your xml

Comment: So what's your question? Do you want to bring a view to the top? If you want to keep everything with same Z than you should align your views at the bottom or at the top of other views so their position won't be behind of any other view. Please post your xml file code otherwise it will be hard for us to give you a better answer.

Comment: In relative layout the z-order depends how the views are initialized, so the view at the top in RelativeLayout will have lowest z-order and vie ew at the bottom of RelativeLayout will have highest z-order and will be above all the views but that aint holding true

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot where the textview is hidden by the button please?

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:elevation="2dp"` to your view `v2`. This will bring it to the top of other views.

**Edit:** Code method

Add the following to your `Activity` class: `yourView.bringToFront();`